# Передача параметров через переменные среды для одного из дочерних процессов

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно передать параметр UserProfile в дочерний процесс.

Не могу понять как это работает.

Есть два проекта один из которых создает дочерний процесс.

Я так понимаю нужно использовать SetEnvironmentVariable(L"UserProfile", L"***") , но не пойму какой аргумент нужно вписать во второе поле!

Comment: Ну а какой вам нужен-то?... И не "сменные", наверное, а переменные?

Comment: SetEnvironmentVariable изменяет переменные окружения в текущем процессе. Для дочернего их следует задавать при создании процесса.

Comment: @user7860670 какой именно параметр отвечает за это в функции CreateProcess ??

Comment: Environment что-то там